# Resizing Bootstrap 3.1.1 Navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I had a quick question regarding twitter bootstrap navbars.  I'm attempting to change the width of my navbar to only occupy 80% of the page width and centered on the page.

I've tried setting the width of .navbar, .nav, .navbar-collapse to 80%, all either doing nothing or shrinking the navbar way too much.

Link to the code:
http://pastebin.com/fHWJfYTL

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You want it to be 80% width and centered?

Comment: Yes, 80% of the page width and centered on the page.  Sorry for not being more specific in my question, I'll edit that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the selectors (media queries) used in BS3, if you want to stay consistent:

```
@media(max-width:767px){}
@media(min-width:768px){}
@media(min-width:992px){}
@media(min-width:1200px){}
```

This is still accurate as of version 3.1.1

<kbd>[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/LmLhK/3/)</kbd>

css

```
@media(max-width:767px) {
    .navbar {
        max-width:80%;
        margin:auto;
        /* float: left;  or right as you want and then remove margin: auto*/
    }

}
@media(min-width:768px) {
/* add here also if you want to have big menu 80% width */
}
@media(min-width:992px) {
/* add here also if you want to have big menu 80% width */
}
@media(min-width:1200px) {
/* add here also if you want to have big menu 80% width */
}
```

Comment: This worked, thank you.  I'm sure the other solutions worked as well, so thank you to the others who answered.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
.navbar {
    margin: auto;
    width: 80%;
}
```